# Creating Keras custom callback for validation

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I want to create a custom callback that evaluates performance on a validation set, at the end of each training epoch. The performance is evaluated using custom metric. Also early stopping should be essential part of the training and validation process.

Here is my code for this validation callback:

```
class ValidationCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, X, Y, Batch_dev, output_shape, patience=0):
        super(ValidationCallback, self).__init__()
        self.patience = patience
        self.best = np.Inf
        self.best_weights = None

        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.Batch_dev = Batch_dev
        self.output_shape = output_shape

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        self.best = np.PZERO
        self.val_uas = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        val = Validation(self.X, self.Y, self.Batch_dev, self.output_shape, self.model)
        _, _, ua_score = val.validate(epoch)
        self.val_uas.append(ua_score)
        logs['val_ua'] = ua_score
        current = logs.get('val_ua')
        if np.less(self.best, current):
            print(self.wait, self.patience)
            print(current, self.best)
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
            self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model_stop_training = True
                print(self.wait, self.patience)
                print(current, self.best)
                print('Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.')
                self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0:
            print('Epoch %05d: early stopping' % (self.stopped_epoch + 1))
```

The training is called as below:

```
validation = ValidationCallback(dev_x, dev_y, batch_size, output_shape, patience=10)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor='loss', patience=10, verbose=1, factor=0.8, min_lr=0.000001
    )
mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint(
    model_name, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_ua', mode='max'
    )
tensorboard = TensorBoard(
    log_dir='./LOGS/log', batch_size=batch_size
    )

hist = model.fit_generator(
    generator=generate_batch_train(train_x, train_y, batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(len(train_x)/batch_size),
    epochs=epochs,
    shuffle=True,
    callbacks=[validation, reduce_lr, mcp_save, tensorboard],
    workers=10,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    max_queue_size=100,
    verbose=1,
)
```

I get the error below, which is strange because neither `val` nor `epoch` is NoneType in `val.validate(epoch)`. Am I doing anything wrong here? Thanks!

```
Epoch 1/200
70/70 [==============================] - 33s 466ms/step - loss: 1.2720 - UAcc: 0.3852
<data_prepare2.Validation object at 0x7fdb920fc240>
0
Valuating test set...
Epoch: 0, acc: 0.3323330372676745, ua: 0.31934171326259553

0 10
0.31934171326259553 0.0
Epoch 2/200
70/70 [==============================] - 19s 278ms/step - loss: 1.1851 - UAcc: 0.4285
<data_prepare2.Validation object at 0x7fdb91a6eb38>
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ser_learning4.py", line 190, in <module>
    verbose=1,
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 251, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/data/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 79, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "ser_learning4.py", line 120, in on_epoch_end
    _, _, ua_score = val.validate(epoch)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What is Validation? It probably returns nothing.

Comment: Hi, Validation is a class that does the evaluation on a validation set by calling validate(). It doesn't returns nothing, as the code prints "<data_prepare2.Validation object at 0x7fdb91a6eb38>", which is assigned to val and should be ready to use..

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I should have asked about val.validate, that one returns nothing (None).

Comment: You're right. I have mistakenly set a if condition in the validate() function and it makes it returns nothing. Thanks a lot Matias!!